# How do I tell Drupal 8 to use my custom module's theme template when rendering an image that is linked?

Tags: 8

I'm building a custom module to extend the default image field. It adds additional attributes that relate to the image field on a per content type basis. At this point it will take and store the attributes => values and when calling hook_preprocess_field() they can be returned (printed) so I can rest assured that they are indeed storing and relating correctly. The final part of the puzzle is to assign my twig template and insert my custom attributes. I thought that hook_theme() would do the job but so far I have failed and I can't find any suitable documentation on the subject when it comes to fields or image fields.

How do I tell Drupal to use my custom module's template when rendering an image that is linked?

Comment: What do you mean by "extend the default image field"? This could be creating a new field type, changing the plugin class to use your own class, making a template for image render types.

Comment: @mradliffe, thanks for chiming in. I wasn't sure if this question would gain any traction. By extending, I mean that I don't want to change the field formatter on the display settings page for the content type. I just want to add options for a few attributes (rel, target, class). This is specific to image fields and specific to the image linking to "file". I have built custom field formatters for other projects but in this case, I am specifically interested in extending the default image field formatter rather than creating a new one. Thanks for any assistance/feedback you can provide.

Comment: A little more digging shows that the default image formatter is located at: 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig'. I need to override that and provide my own within my module. hook_theme() doesn't seem to do the job. I may be able to use hook_theme_registry_alter(), providing I can get it to use the path I give it to my module. It may be a little heavy handed though.

Comment: I understand now. If you want to override the class used by a field type, then `hook_field_info_alter` is the only way. Change the `$info['image']['class']` or what not to your new class. And then it needs a `drush cr && drush entup` I think you don't need to provide an annotation. I haven't tried that before.

Comment: Thanks for that... I've now been looking at the `hook_field_info_alter()` and it might be useful to change the `$info['image'][default_formatter]` to my own in its place. I've been looking at a lot of approaches on this so I need to give it some more thought first.

Comment: @mradcliffe, thanks for the help. I couldn't find a solution with `hook_field_info_alter()` I ended up using `hook_theme_registry_alter()` and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The solution was to use: `hook_theme_registry_alter()`

`/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
 */
function MY_MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['image_formatter']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/templates/field';
}`

In my module I have the templates/field directory with the template `image-formatter.html.twig`, so no other changes were necessary.